# Use results from two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov to compare methods

Tags: probability, distributions, statistical-significance, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

Let say I observe a phenomenon an I get its PDF. Then I come up with two models to simulate this phenomenon. From these models, I can get a PDF and I want to know which model is better.

I am not interested in the $Q_2$ of the model. Here the objective is to get the PDF to assess threashold exceeding or to see how the phenomenon responds to uncertainties for instance. Maybe there is a bi-modal structure, particular values with particular level of probabilities, etc. This is for exploratory so no particular quantile is targeted and thus I need the PDF from the model which represents best the PDF from the real observations.

So let’s say I have:

- One sample from observation giving `PDF1`,
- One sample from the first model giving `PDF2`,
- One sample from the second model giving `PDF3`.

I am not a statistician, so from my findings I have to use a Kolmogorov-Smirnov test to assess if two PDFs can be considered "equal".

Thus, I compute two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test with `PDF1` vs `PDF2` giving `pvalue1` and from `PDF1` vs `PDF3` giving `pvalue2`.

Can I compare the two `pvalues`? If `pvalue1 < pvalue2`, can I say that the first model is better?

Or maybe this approach is wrong, so how to tell which model is better at getting the PDF (only the PDF, I know about Q2 and this is not what I am looking for)?

Comment: What would the two samples be?  So far your description implies only one sample: namely, your observations.

Comment: @whuber there is the observation and then using each model you have new predictions. Is that clear?

Comment: Yes, but why are you going about it this way?  The one-sample K-S test specifically compares a sample to a distribution: there's no need to generate a new artificial "sample" to run the test.  Your basic problem is that when you generate a model from data, it's not valid to test the model against the same data: the logic is circular and, even though you can carry out the K-S calculations, its p-value won't be meaningful.  If you're concerned about predictive validity, then the K-S test is practically irrelevant anyway.

Comment: @whuber I am using the two sided test because I just have samples from the observation. My understanding is that the one sample KS requires a distribution and some sample. Here I have two sets of sample. Hence the two sided test. The goal of all this is to find which model is better at finding the observed PDF. So I thought that comparing pvalues could do this.

Comment: We seem to be going back and forth.  As far as I can tell, you have never described more than one actual sample: everything else comes from some model you have created.  There's no need to sample from a model in order to compare it to data.  Rather than insisting on this approach, you would be better off abandoning it and changing your question so that it formulates a clear objective, describes the information you have, and asks how to achieve that objective.  You will likely discover that our site has a great many threads about model selection and comparison, so consider searching.

Comment: @whuber why being so rude!? It is not because I am not using the right wording and that you do not get what I à asking that you can bully. And your reputation here does not give you this right either. So going back to the question. I have two different surrogate models trying to predict some physics and the objective is to compute the PDF. So I do not care here about the predictivity coefficient Q2. So now, how to say that model A is better than model B to get the PDF. Given that I have the budget to get the empirical PDF by doing a large sampling.

Comment: I am sorry you find this exchange rude--I'm only trying to assist you in formulating an effective question.  Of course I'm not fully understanding, but that's a sign many others who might be in a position to help you might fail to understand or even misunderstand what you're after. You're certainly welcome to keep your question up, but my impression is that in its present form it's not likely to get answers that truly help, and the comments haven't clarified much.

Comment: @Y0da whuber was not being rude, but rather trying to help you solve your problem. You have posted a question in the form of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/202463) (see also [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)) - asking about an attempted solution to a problem (simulating and using two sample KS tests) rather than explaining the problem itself. Your attempted approach is clearly unsuitable but you don't explain your underlying situation clearly enough to really offer good advice about what you should do instead..

Comment: @Glen_b I am not a statistician at all. From my search, I found that KS test would be the way to assess if two PDFs can be considered equal. Maybe this is not the correct approach, but I just don’t know why. As I said in my last comment to whuber, I want to tell which model give me the best PDF.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, you're getting closer to an answerable question that has a hope of giving you useful advice, but a little more is needed. "Best" is not defined yet. If you don't have an operational definition of 'best' for your problem (essentially, an algebraic formula or something from which one could be derived) - and I suggest you don't attempt one - you'll require advice about what might at least do fairly well in your circumstances. The problem is we shouldn't be suggesting any if we don't have a good understanding of what you'll be doing with it (i.e. without the circumstances)

Comment: @Glen_b I do not have any more context than comparing two surrogate model’s  capabilities to recover a PDF. Best here means that on overall the PDF from one surrogate would be closer than with the other surrogate. So there is no particular focus on some specific quantiles.

Comment: 1. What's the point in estimating a pdf? It's not normally a goal in and of itself -- after you estimate a pdf, you're using that estimated pdf to do *something*, right? It's *that* that you should seek to do well at. 2. Closer measured *how*? With two values there's an infinite number of ways to define a distance between them.  But these are two *functions*. You're simply substituting one undefined term (closer) for another (best).

Comment: @Glen_b the goal is the PDF. In risk analysis for instance, they are interested in the probability to exceed a threashold. And sometimes you just do not have any threashold but you are interested to know how the system responds (uncertainty quantification). I am in this framework. I need to have a mean to compare the ability of a surrogate to retrieve the PDF.

Comment: It would be a good idea to put your most recent comment in the question.  "The probability to exceed a threshold" is certainly a goal. One way to get it is to try to identify a pdf, but it's often not the best way to achieve that goal  (in part it depends on how far into the tail the threshold is). If I were nevertheless going to try to identify a pdf for that purpose, I probably wouldn't be  using K-S distance but something that would do better in the tail. Then, if you were nevertheless to use KS distance anyway, you don't do it the way you were trying to do it (as whuber explained). ...ctd

Comment: ctd... You can also get a good idea how a system behaves without identifying a distributional form for data, since you have the ECDF itself

Comment: @Glen_b thanks I updated the question. But I do not understand how a can use the one sided KS here. Or maybe I just do not get the real difference between these two tests.

Comment: It's not the *one sided* version of the KS test that's at issue, it's the *one sample* version. But you can't use it directly if you're estimating parameters

Comment: @Glen_b That’s my understanding and this is why I wanted to use the two-sample version. So is this correct?

Comment: No, the two-sample version has *exactly* the same problem (it's wrong if you do parameter estimation), plus it has a number of additional issues. It's worse than doing the one-sample test which is already wrong.  I think there's now enough here for the question to be more or less answerable, but most of the issues here are addressed in other questions already on site.

Comment: @Glen_b OK... I really do not get this then. Thanks for your time. Any advice then about the way I should compare my models?

Comment: Now that's a good question to ask -- and a reasonable answer is too long for a comment. Why not post that one? You can leave this one if you like; I'll try to turn my comments into an answer here.

Comment: @Glen_b OK I will do this and let you know when the question is out thanks.

Comment: Search first, though, as whuber advised way back near the start of these comments.

Comment: @Glen_b indeed I see this one https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/25923/140570

Comment: It doesn't have an answer though. If you have tried a number of searches but can't find any answers, you can post it.

Answer (score 1):

A two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test comparing data to values simulated from a model is not a good way to see whether a distributional model fits the data.

In the case where you have not estimated any parameters, it's simply a much less efficient way of doing a one-sample K-S test. You can improve its efficiency by drawing a larger simulation sample. As the sample size goes to infinity, guess what you end up with? The one-sample K-S test!

Neither test is suitable (as is) if you estimate parameters, though.

One of the things you're after is to be able to estimate the probability to exceed a threshold. One way to get it is to try to identify a pdf, but it's often not the best way to achieve that goal  (in part it depends on how far into the tail the threshold is). If the thresholds are near the middle, you may, for example, be better to estimate these directly from the data.

if those threshholds are not mostly near the middle, it may make sense try to identify a pdf for that purpose, but then I probably wouldn't be using K-S distance to assess fit, but something that would do better in the tail.

(You can also get a good idea how a system behaves without identifying a distributional form for data, since you have the ECDF itself)

However; if you need information about the extreme tail (beyond almost all the data) then the data isn't much use; you need some assumptions as well.

Now lastly, none of this is necessarily of the greatest use for deciding between two competing models.

Comment: Some points, but this answer does not answer the last question. If this method is not good, what to use? As I explained I really want the PDF. I want to know which model of my creation will be better at estimating the PDF (and when I have the model, I can create an near to infinite sample). This is for exploratory reason. Threashold exceeding is just an example and prior to getting the PDF, we just don’t know what we want to do with the problem.

Comment: The last question (which you added yesterday) makes this question overly broad. If you deny any specific purpose and offer no explicit loss function there's not much to say (other than "when you have a loss function, minimize it"). This issue was explained in comments. I have given examples of the sort of considerations that come into designing a loss function for some purpose. If you want to use KS distance as a loss you can do so but (besides it appearing to be arbitrarily chosen), the problem is you cannot reasonably compare models with different numbers of parameters that way. ... ctd

Comment: ctd... You might try out of sample loss (via cross validation perhaps); this would make particularly good sense if your problems in the future were mostly predictive in nature

Comment: that is the whole point of my question. Is this valid to use KS as a metric. From what you say now the answer is yes although you say this metric would be arbitrary (I just do not understand what are the parameters). But this is true for all metrics, all are arbitrary chosen. In this case I wanted to know if the community had came up with a standard way of doing this or not as I did not find it in the literature. Again, in uncertainty propagation you want the whole PDF and this is the final result. So if you are able to compare your model with a database you want a metric for that.

Comment: No, not all metrics are arbitrary; if they're chosen to suit what you're doing they're not arbitrary. There are a variety of ways people use to choose between competing distribution choices -- many questions on site relate to this.

Comment: I guess I will leave this here... you guys are playing with words and I explained several times in different ways my problem. I spoke with leading experts in uncertainty analysis today and they understood right away the issue and did not see fundamental objections with this method. So thanks anyway for your time. I guess this community is really not for me as you guys just speaks with each other’s and want to answer your questions and not mines... Just a tired guy speaking